# Load more button not properly working with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

please I have a question. the code below  uses load more button to display records. 
 I set the limit to 2. the problem is  that  it displays the first 2 records and on the next click, 
it shows the remaining 6 records instead of showing in two's (2's)based on limit as user click. 
Can someone help me fix this issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>


<style>

.pic{
background:blue; color:white;}
</style>


<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">




class Application extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.state = {rec : [
     { "name" : "Tony", "Age" : "18"},
     { "name" : "John", "Age" : "21" },
     { "name" : "Luke", "Age" : "78" },
     { "name" : "Mark", "Age" : "90" },
     { "name" : "Jame", "Age" : "87" },
     { "name" : "Franco", "Age" : "34" },
     { "name" : "Biggard", "Age" : "19" },
     { "name" : "tom", "Age" : "89" },
   ],    
   limit : 2};
   this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
 }

 loadMore() {
   let recLength = this.state.rec.length;
   this.setState({limit:recLength});
   // show more entries
   // switch to "show less"
 }
 render() {
   return <div className="container">

     <div>
       <h3>List of Records</h3>
       <ul>
         {this.state.rec.slice(0,this.state.limit).map((obj, i) => 
<li key={i}>{obj.name} - {obj.Age}</li>
)}
       </ul>
     </div>
     <p>
       <a className="pic" onClick={this.loadMore}>Load more Button</a>.
<br />
//display image spinner as user clicks on load more button
     </p>
   </div>;
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour based on your code. When you click loadMore, you reassign the limit to be the length of the this.state.rec array. In this case, the length will always be 8. So it will just show the entire array. If you want to increment the list by only 2 until the limit, I would do this.

```
loadMore() {
   const recLength = this.state.rec.length;
   const currentLimit = this.state.limit;
   if (currentLimit < recLength) {
      this.setState({ limit: currentLimit + 2 });
   }
 }

get doneMessage() {
    if (this.state.limit >= this.state.rec.length) {
       return (<li key={'done'}>All messages loaded.</li>);
    }
    return null;
}

render() {
   return <div className="container">

     <div>
       <h3>List of Records</h3>
       <ul>
         {this.state.rec.slice(0,this.state.limit).map((obj, i) => 
             <li key={i}>{obj.name} - {obj.Age}</li>
         )}
         {this.doneMessage}
       </ul>
     </div>
     <p>
      <a className="pic" onClick={this.loadMore}>
         Load more Button
      </a>
     </p>
   </div>;
 }
}
```

Slight correction, forgot slice won't out of bounds you (lol javascript). I also added some code on how you could possibly display a no more messages dialogue.

As for displaying an image spinner, that can't really be applied in this situation. Your load more here is instantaneous. If it were doing some sort of large operation or a network fetch I would advise having one, otherwise it's rather pointless. If you did add one, it would be done similarly to the done message.

Comment: You don't have to worry about the limit being greater than `rec.length`. It will give an index out of range so it will just return everything up to that index (which will be everything in the array).

Comment: @Ramzi C. Your solution is okay but how do i print message  "no more record to load " if there is no more record to display. can i display also a loading image as user clicks on load more button. Thanks

Comment: Added some changes for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your `loadMore` method, you are setting the limit to the length of the records:

```
let recLength = this.state.rec.length;
this.setState({limit:recLength});
```

When you first get the records, you are doing a `slice` getting the first 2 (since `this.state.limit` is 2). But after this, when you click the button, the limit is set to the amount of records (8), which means it will get all 8.

Answer (score 0):

The `loadMore` function should increment `this.state.limit` by 2 each time:

```
 loadMore() {
   this.setState({ limit: this.state.limit + 2 });
 }
```